# C# Windows service self terminate service

Tags: c#, windows-services

How do you have a service self terminate?

Environment.Exit will cause the app to start but the service stays running.

Any idea?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the SCM to shut down your service from within the service itself:

```
System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController svc = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController("NameOfYourService");
svc.Stop();
```

**Edit:**

The other option is to call [`ServiceBase.Stop()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.stop.aspx) in your service - if you have access to your `ServiceBase` derived class instance that would be the cleaner way to go - in many cases it is cumbersome though having to pass this dependency around.

If you have an uncaught exception I personally would just let the service crash (or log it and then `throw`), which will leave a message in the event log detailing the termination reason. If you absolutely need to you can catch the Exception, and then call `ServiceBase.Stop()`.

Comment: can i use this inside of an exception outside of the class that starts the service?

Comment: @Mike: Updated with some more explanation - not sure if I understand you correctly on the "inside of an exception" part - can you explain?

Comment: well i have a try{} catch{} which in encased inside of a while{}.  The problem is if this try fails I need those whole service to stop.  I call the service to stop on Service1.cs, i need this is happen in an different class

Comment: @Mike: What part of this is not working? If `Service1` derives from `ServiceBase` you can just add a public method that then calls `base.Stop()` - or if you don't want or have a reference to `Service1` you can use the SCM instead.

Comment: so on service1.cs i put this
        public static void ForceStop()
        {

            Service1.ForceStop();
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }

then can i call it from my other class in my catch{Service1.ForceStop()}?

Comment: @Mike - you don't need the `Environment.Exit(1)` part. Also this cannot be a static method since you want to call `base.Stop()` within that method - this means that other class you have needs a reference to an instance of `Service1` so you can call a public method on it.

Comment: but doesn't {Service1.ForceStop() contain a reference to Service1? Or am I wrong here?

Comment: @Mike: No if you call a **static** method you don't need an instance reference- but you also cannot use properties of an instance or call any other instance / base class methods - just make sure you actually have an object reference and implement the method like this:  `public void ForceStop() { base.Stop(); }`

Comment: okay, dont laugh, but i don't know how to set an object reference, for the code above what would be the object refence?

Comment: i cant locate .stop for servicebase

Comment: @Mike: Does Service1 inherit from `ServiceBase`? It's hard to help since I don't know you code - if you could post the relevant code that exhibits the problem you have as part of the question, that would help.